# How to assign players to teams in a game

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm creating a game with different participants that belong to different teams.
I having trouble assigned the players to the teams. 
The players exist in an ArrayList, and i have created lists for each of the teams as well, but is it even possible to assign an element of one list to another list? So that the player exists in both lists?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can add items from one list into another. What have you tried?

Comment: Your question appears to be both very broad and very vague. To help us help you, please clarify by showing code, by explaining in fair detail how your current code attempt is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The list object contains an array of methods for adding and removing elements from lists: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

I'd suggest something like :
`teamList.add(playerList.get(playerIndex))`

where playIndex is an integer of the player you want to add to the team. Assuming your players and teams are the same object type, the above code will retrieve a player from the player list and add that player to your team list.